# Is there one easy way to assign a one to many relationship to objects in C# without using ORM?

Tags: c#, sql

I particularly don't like ORMs but I am getting into situations that  I cannot think of a logic that is simple enough to solve the problem.

For example, if a have a category table that has a "one to many relationship" with subcategory, a query could produce something like this:

```
category     subcategory
eletronics    keyboards
eletronics    mouses
fashion       t-shirt
fashion        hat
```

I cannot think of a simple logic to "map" it to an object like below using a datareader:

```
public class Category
{
  public string Category {get ; set;}
  public List<Subcategory> Subcategory {get; set;} new Subcategory();
}
```

I performed the same task using Eloquent in a Laravel application and it was a breeze.

I am considering installing a ORM package and using object relational mapper to perform this task and use raw sql commands on the rest of the application.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: you could certainly use a data reader and write your own mapping.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tutorials for this, but to give you an example that can be found over at the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<SubCategory> SubCategory {get; set;}
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Parent {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then you would have a method like...

```
static List<Category> RetrieveCategories(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT Id, Name FROM dbo.Categories;" +
          "SELECT Id, Parent, Name FROM dbo.SubCategories",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<Category> result = new List<Category>();

        // grab the categories
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var category = new Category()
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                Name = reader.GetString(1)
                SubCategory = new List<SubCategory>();
            };

            result.Add(category);
        }

        sqlReader.NextResult();

        // grab the sub categories
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var subCategory = new SubCategory()
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                Parent = reader.GetString(1),
                Name = reader.GetString(2)
            };

            // add the sub categories to the results
            results.Where(_ => _.Name == subcategory.Parent)
                   .FirstOrDefault()
                   .SubCategory.Add(subcategory);

        }
    }
}
```

Please note this isn't really highly optimized code, but it is only to illustrate that it is indeed possible to populate your own class from various tables using `DataReader`.

Comment: I don't see how this is a relevant answer. I didn't click the link to see the original doc, but the code in your answer is simply loading all categories and all employees. Where is the relationship between them?

Comment: Sorry- I did indeed make some errors, I updated it accordingly.

Comment: The updated code is even worse. It still has no relationship and you have two classes called `Category`.

Comment: It's  a bit late, the second one was meant to be the SubCategory.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- omg.... thanks.

Comment: OK, it's a bit better now, but just as an example. Using such code in a real product is a terrible idea. Loading everything and linking them together in code is terrible in most cases where you only need some of the data. A well designed software only loads data as needed. One way to achieve that is via lazy loading. Similar to what LINQ and EF do.

Comment: @RacilHilan I agree this is not good for production. I was trying my best to answer to his request for "simple logic to "map" it to an object like below using a datareader" -- so I tried to make it as simple as possible (at least to read).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to develop a simple code and for now I will not install an ORM package.

if a have a result set like this:

```
 id(category id)  category_name subcategory_name
 1                 eletronic      keyboard
 1                 eletronic        mouse
 2                  fashion         t-shirt
 2                   fashion         hat
```

The result set must be ordered by id,
  I can do something like this:

```
 List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();

 //I will use this variable to hold the category id of the row that the datareader is reading
  int categoryId= 0;  

  Category category = null;

    while (dr.Read())
        {    
             //if the current category id is different than the variable categoryId I will instantiante a new Category,
            // otherwise I will add the a new subcategory to the existing category object

            if(categoryId != dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("id")))
                { 
                    category = new Category();
                    category.CategoryName =   dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("category_name"));

                    category.Subcategory.Add(new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("subcategory_name")) });

                }
                else
                {
                    category.Subcategory.Add(new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("subcategory_name")) });

                }

                if (categoryId != dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("id")) && category !=null)
                {
                    categorias.Add(category);
                }

              categoryId =  dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("id"));
            }


            conn.Close();

            return categories;
```

Basically I iterate the result set if the id changes I instantiate a new Category otherwise I add a new Subcategory to the current Category object.